# Getting the perforce changelist for multiple projects through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

Apologies in advance for my Jenkins knowledge, started using it recently.

I have multiple projects under the same depot. Therefore I've only got one perforce mapping in the Jenkins.
I want to get the latest changelist number for each project. The environmental variable P4_CHANGELIST only lists the latest for the whole depot.
Therefore I tried to invoke a post build CMD process for each project to query the changelist number

```
p4 changes -m1 //path/to/project1 
p4 changes -m1 //path/to/project2
```

Then Jenkins trigger an error `Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT`. But the command works in my machine. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have Jenkins execute p4 info and compare that to your results of the command

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22689539/193453

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, still couldn't get to work. So this is my solution.

Instead if mapping the parent directory of multiple projects and building them all, I created multiple Jenkins projects with a single mapping in each. In this way each Jenkins project has the final changelist of perforce project (in the environmental variable P4_CHANGELIST). Thereafter I created a pipeline project at use a simple Groovy scripts to build all my projects. Now I have all the latest changelists of all the projects.
I know its naive, but got my job done.